# Tangent Space of a one-dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, topology

Is the tangent space of a one-dimensional smooth manifold always trivial, i.e. is $TM \cong M \times R$?

Comment: Is there a non-trivial difference between a straight line and a circle? I believe so.

Comment: @FlatterMann the fact that they’re different (not homeomorphic) is irrelevant since both their tangent bundles are trivializable. For $\Bbb{R}$, it is obvious, while for $S^1$, one uses the existence of the rotation field (a nowhere vanishing tangent vector field).

Comment: @peek-a-boo The physics on that tangent bundle isn't trivializable. The solutions to a quantum theory on those two manifolds are very, very different. Geometry is simply not the end of it. Maybe this should have been posted on the math SE, instead, if this is the requested answer?

Comment: @FlatterMann :  You can argue about where this should have been posted but the question is entirely unambiguous and certainly not about quantum theory.

Comment: @WillO: I am not arguing about the mathematical answer. I am simply giving a physics comment. The two manifolds do not behave the same for the purposes of physics. which tells us something important: physics doesn't always live on the tangent bundle alone, even if we often like to think that way. I, too, like telling people that "all physics is local", because that is not completely wrong. It's also not completely correct. The global picture matters for some systems and gives us some rather interesting effects. No offense intended. I did upvote your answer, by the way.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @FlatterMann I would be the last person here to say to avoid global issues. But the answer here is unambiguous. Yes, $S^1$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are very different and these differences manifest in all sorts of interesting ways, but the answer to OP’s question is an unambiguous yes. Both $S^1$ and $\Bbb{R}$ have trivializable tangent bundles $T\Bbb{R}\cong \Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$ and $TS^1\cong S^1\times\Bbb{R}$. It seems you’re trying to adopt a different meaning to the term “trivializable”, which is **very** weird here (to say the least).

Answer (score 5):

The only one-dimensional manifolds are a circle and a line, each of which has a trivial tangent bundle.  So yes.